# selenium - download file to /tmp not there

Tags: selenium, download

When I download a file in Ubuntu to `/tmp` using selenium, the file doesn't appear. However, the count postfix of the filename keeps increasing in Chrome, e.g. `file (1).txt` - meaning the browser finds the previously downloaded files.

Example `App.java`:

```
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException {
        final ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", Map.of("download.default_directory", "/tmp/"));

        final ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("file:///home/.../download.html");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

`download.html`

```
<div>Hello</div>
<script>
const element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent("Hello World"));
element.setAttribute('download', "file.txt");

element.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(element);

element.click();

document.body.removeChild(element);
</script>
```

After running this java code, the file cannot be found in `/tmp` or anywhere else in the filesystem: `find . 2>/dev/null -name file.txt` yields nothing. However, while the code is running, selenium keeps increasing the postfix of the filename:
[image: filename postfix]

Where is the downloaded file?

Comment: I think forward slashes could be an issue, can you try with `options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", Map.of("download.default_directory", "\tmp\"));`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the files are downloaded into your `/home/username/Downloads` folder, not to `/tmp` folder as you expecting.